# Creating dynamic routes based on Vue.js components in Nuxt.js Navigation

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, router

I'm developing a Vue.js project using Nuxt.js, and I'm facing an issue with dynamically generating routes based on components. I have a navigation drawer with menu items, each linked to a specific Vue component. Here's a snippet of my **`nuxt.config.js`**:

```
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  router: {
    middleware: ["auth"],
    extendRoutes(routes) {
      routes.push(
        // ... other routes
        { path: '/userPanel/myBooks', component: '@/pages/userPanel/myBooks/index.vue', meta: { title: 'کتاب های من' } },
        { path: '/userPanel/bookMarkedBooks', component: '@/pages/userPanel/bookMarkedBooks/index.vue', meta: { title: 'کتاب های نشان شده' } },
        // ... other routes
      );
    },
  },
  // ... other configurations
};
I have a breadcrumbs component in the layouts folder that should dynamically display the page title. Here's the relevant part:
<!-- breadcrumbs.vue -->
<div>
  <!-- ... other content -->
  <span class="body4-medium n500--text">{{ pageTitle }}</span>
  <!-- ... other content -->
</div>
In my userPanel layout, I'm using this breadcrumbs component:
<!-- userPanel.vue -->
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <!-- ... other components -->
      <breadcrumbs :pageTitle="pageTitle" />
      <!-- ... other components -->
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import breadcrumbs from "@/layouts/breadcrumbs.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    breadcrumbs,
  },
  computed: {
    pageTitle() {
      return this.$route.meta.title || '';
    },
  },
};
</script>
Despite the configurations, I'm encountering an error related to module not found in the .nuxt/router.js file. I've tried different path configurations, but the issue persists. How can I resolve this problem and achieve dynamic routes based on components?
```

I expected the routes to be dynamically created based on the specified components, allowing navigation to these components through the menu items in my navigation drawer.

Comment: Why don't you use the default route that nuxt already supports.
When you put the file `userPanel/myBooks/index.vue` in the `pages` folder, Nuxt will automatically create the router `/userPanel/myBooks` for you without you having to configure further in nuxt.config.js. Similar to the file `userPanel/bookMarkedBooks/index.vue`, you just need to put it in the `pages` folder and nuxt will create the router `userPanel/bookMarkedBooks`